# JDBC Communications link failure with Docker Compose

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When my Spring Boot app tries to connect to the MySQL-database, it throws a CommunicationsException:

```
spring-service_1  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
spring-service_1  |
spring-service_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

As far as I can tell, my `docker-compose.yml` is correct, as well as my `Dockerfile` which simply builds and moves the `jar`. I've tried changing around some application properties, but it always ends up either in this Connection Exception, or the database refusing access after building my `jar` and using `docker-composer up` or `docker-composer up --build`.

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  mysql-service:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - spring-boot-mysql-network
    volumes:
      - C:/Docker/mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - C:/Docker/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=springuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password123
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=springprototype
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='%'

  spring-service:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - spring-boot-mysql-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql-service

networks:
  spring-boot-mysql-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-hotspot
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 4000
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

My Spring Boot app's `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service:3306/springprototype
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
server.port=4000
```

What could be wrong here? Maybe I'm overlooking or forgetting something.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the network by removing all the extra definitions and using directly the default network because you only have two services.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  mysql-service:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - C:/Docker/mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - C:/Docker/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=springuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password123
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=springprototype
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='%'

  spring-service:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-service
```